# How to get Facebook developer app contracts?

Tags: facebook

I am setting up an app through Facebook. The app needs to have the "Publis_Pages" and "Manage_Pages" permissions. Is there any way to get the contracts associated with certain permissions before completing the app so I can look over the contracts before hand?

Comment: What “contracts” are you talking about?

Comment: In their documentation the process of getting an app approved it goes through a series of steps, one of those steps is "Sign Contracts",I assume that those contracts pertain to what permissions you are requesting. This is found under your app in the app review step